# CORS in .NET CORE 2.1 - no header returned for simple configuration

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, cors, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I basically followed this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.1 trying to set it up properly in my project, but so far without lack. I think I tried every combination, both with middle were and services, changing order etc.

When testing with the postman, I don't see any header related to CORS when doing POST call to my API endpoint.

My app that is consuming the API, and running on `http:/localhost:3000` is getting CORS error when trying to make a POST call to the API endpoint.

Here is my entire `Startup.cs` class:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        HostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public IHostingEnvironment HostingEnvironment { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddInjectionByAttribute();

        services.AddDbContext<MoneyTrackigContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDbContext<UserContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("UserDbConnection")));                       

        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(o =>
        {
            o.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            o.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            o.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            o.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
        })
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<UserContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear(); // => remove default claims
        services.AddAuthentication(o =>
        {
            o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            o.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            o.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment();
            cfg.SaveToken = true;
            cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidIssuer = Configuration.GetSection("JwtOptions")["JwtIssuer"],
                ValidAudience = Configuration.GetSection("JwtOptions")["JwtIssuer"],
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration.GetSection("JwtOptions")["JwtKey"])),
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero // remove delay of token when expire
            };
        });

        services.AddAuthorization(o =>
        {
            o.AddPolicy(Policy.DefaultUser, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimName.User));
        });

        services.AddAutoMapper();

        services.AddCors();
        services.AddMvc();

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseCors(b => b.WithOrigins("http:/localhost:3000").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Have I missed something obvious? Any ideas what might be causing this issue. The entire thing seems pretty straightforward but got stuck with it.

Comment: Just for anyone who comes across this, there's a slash missing from the protocol in "b.WithOrigins" where the origin is set.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to add an Origin header in Postman to get an corresponding response.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason.
.NET CORE doesn't append the CORS headers in case there was an application exception and the request wansn't handled properly. So API return 500 without CORS headers, and browser handles it as CORS error, not api error, thats why I misssed it.
**Config posted in question works fine**